# How do Firebase Cloud Functions ack Cloud pub/sub

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

In this [article on Google Cloud Pub Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber) we are told that a function must return a status to ack receipt of a message.  I have one question related specifically to [Firebase Cloud Functions pubsub triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events):

I cannot see in the document above how or if a Firebase Cloud function acks the pub sub.  Can someone explain this please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is implemented in Google-managed code. It’s effectively the same as a Pub/Sub push subscription, where a 200 response acks the message (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#receive_push). This auto-ack happens after your function finishes successfully.

Comment: Do you mean cloud pub sub trigger retry when function fails to succeed? Can you site a reference for firebase cloud functions where its mentioned?

Comment: The failurePolicy attribute of your function decides whether the trigger retries when the function fails.

Comment: Ok. so it means its not equivalent to normal http push subscription where it retries automatically if other than 2XX status code is sent. Thanks for clarifying. But having http push subscriptions sounds reliable as eventhough with error and no retry policy set, we miss the information with triggers.

Comment: It is a normal HTTP push subscription under the covers. It's just that without a retry policy set the Google-managed code returns 200 even if your code errors. This is a cost-effective default because it prevents an unbounded bill in a query of death situation.

Comment: Want to add some clarification since I think you might have a misunderstanding @Ayyappa. When you tell GCF that you don't want retries, the handler explicitly sends a 200 response to ACK the Pub/Sub message when your code has an error. If there's an infrastructure error, no 200 is sent and the message is retried. Pub/Sub is at-least-once even w/o retries enabled.